# ld: warning: ignoring file SpeechKit, missing required architecture x86_64 in (3 slic

Tags: ios, swift, text-to-speech

I am importing SpeechKit.h in brigde header **`#import <SpeechKit/SpeechKit.h>`**
In appdelegate file I just write 1 line :- **

**`SpeechKit.setupWithID("xyz", host: "sslsandbox.nmdp.nuancemobility.net", port: 443, useSSL: true, delegate: nil)`**

**
when I build project it throws errors as shown in image:- 
Tried alot to find any solution but not able to get any solution please help me to resolve it.

[image: Error coming when I build my project]

[image: Added following frameworks]

Comment: What hardware are you targeting? Which version of Xcode are you building with? Try running these on the hardware to see if there is any variance with what you are seeing on the simulator. Did you do the normal things, clean, clear build folder, rebuild, delete app from simulator/phone and recreate? - Answers to these will help clarify the scenario you are facing. Look at the related questions on the right. Do they solve the issue? If yes, then delete the question otherwise update.